# Drop-Down List With Images

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a drop-down list that will display images next to the description of the list.

I have tried a number of methods, but can't seem to get the list to display the images, and I am not sure if this can be done when retrieving my list from a DB.

This is what I have so far, and the list perfectly displays the descriptions, it's only the images I can't get to show:

```
<select name="product_id"  class="form-control" id="product_id" required>
<option value="" disabled selected>-- Ensure you select the correct Element Description (Product Code | Element Name | Colour | Pieces | Price) --</option>
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DATABASE");
$part_list = 
"SELECT DISTINCT
product_id
,   CONCAT(product_id, ' | ', part_description, ' | ', colour, ' | ', piece_count, ' | R ', box_price)  AS 'description'
,   image
FROM
    pab_parts
ORDER BY
    part_description
,   colour
";      
$listresult = mysqli_query($link,$part_list)or die(mysqli_error());     

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listresult)) 
{
echo "<option value='". $row['product_id']." ' data-imagesrc='pieces/". $row['image']." '>".$row['description'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
</div>
```

I have checked my query and can confirm that my query is returning the correct results. So the issue is not on the DB side, but rather on the form itself.

Comment: maybe your markup on that option tag breaks, try to escape output with `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: @Satya Putting `data-src="myimage.jpg"` in an `<option>` is enough to render `myimage.jpg`?

Comment: Your `data-imagesrc=pieces/'". $row['image']." ');>"` is messed up, no starting `'`, what's `);>` doing in there? I don't know any solution (which doesn't mean a lot) that doesn't involve Javascript to show images in a select.

Comment: The `);` was from one of the other options I tried forgot to remove it. I have updated the code as in the question above. Also tried @Satya's suggestion, but not result.

Comment: Do you have Javascript in place that handles those `data-imagesrc` attributes?

Comment: Javascript source `[link]https://github.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/blob/master/jquery.ddslick.js`

Answer (score -1):

As per me, CSS of select option cannot be changed, you may use ul - li for the same

For reference check this link codepen.io/fsanggang/pen/ZOepzE

Comment: Would be nice if you'd explain a little what you changed and why you changed it. Also, that codepen doesn't use `<select>` and `<option>`, how does your code solve OPs problem?